# React Hook not notifying state change to components using the hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

So I have a Hook

```js
export default function useCustomHook() {
    const initFrom = localStorage.getItem("startDate") === null? moment().subtract(14, "d"): moment(localStorage.getItem("startDate"));
    const initTo = localStorage.getItem("endDate") === null? moment().subtract(1, "d"): moment(localStorage.getItem("endDate"));
    
    const [dates, updateDates] = React.useState({
        from: initFrom,
        to: initTo
    });

    const [sessionBreakdown, updateSessionBreakdown] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        api.GET(`/analytics/session-breakdown/${api.getWebsiteGUID()}/${dates.from.format("YYYY-MM-DD")}:${dates.to.format("YYYY-MM-DD")}/0/all/1`).then(res => {
            updateSessionBreakdown(res.item);
            console.log("Updated session breakdown", res);
        })
    },[dates])

    const setDateRange = React.useCallback((startDate, endDate) => {
        const e = moment(endDate);
        const s = moment(startDate);
        localStorage.setItem("endDate", e._d);
        localStorage.setItem("startDate", s._d);
        updateDates((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, to:e, from:s}));
    }, [])

    const getDateRange = () => {
        return [dates.from, dates.to];
    }
    
    return [sessionBreakdown, getDateRange, setDateRange]

}
```

Now, this hook appears to be working in the network inspector, if I call the setDateRanger function I can see it makes the call to our API Service, and get the results back.

However, we have several components that are using the `sessionBreakdown` return result and are not updating when the `updateSessionBreakdown` is being used.

i can also see the promise from the API call is being fired in the console.
[image: Updated session breakdown {status: 'session breakdown data - website: 3d5e9fa4-ac6a-42f9-8f5f-c49168ebe667 (day-by-day)', item: {…}}]

I have created a small version that reproduces the issue I'm having with it at https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-microservice-kq9cck Please note i have changed the code in here so it's not reliant on my API Connector to show the problem,

Comment: Do you want a common state, which can update data in all components using the hook

Comment: @Azzy yes I think that's what I want I want it so every component using the hook re-renders when the `sessionBreakdown` is updated

Comment: will React context work in your case, it requires the parent component to be child of the context provider, if you dont want to do that then  state management libraries like [jotai](https://jotai.org/) can help, the Idea is to have a parent level state that can changed and all children get updated on state change,
I can create a simple example with context if needed

Comment: @Azzy I thought the whole point of hooks was to get away from the inheritance model, how would this work with a `useMemo`, as the actual data being obtained is data for graphing and I have to cache the resulting graphs with `useMemo` or they flash like hell., if a context would work, how would I do it with a context?

Comment: Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hodgkin-xd1bz6?file=/src/CustomContext.js) demo, context will re render its children on every state update, if that does not work for you may be jotai could reduce those re-renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update object for useState, recommended way is to use callback and spread operator.

```
updateDates((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, to:e, from:s}));
```

Additionally, please use `useCallback` if you want to use `setDateRange` function in any other components.

```
const setDateRange = useCallback((startDate, endDate) => {
    const e = moment(endDate);
    const s = moment(startDate);
    localStorage.setItem("endDate", e._d);
    localStorage.setItem("startDate", s._d);
    updateDates((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, to:e, from:s}));
}, [])
```

Found the problem:
You are calling `CustomHook` in 2 components separately, it means your local state instance created separately for those components. So Even though you update state in one component, it does not effect to another component.

To solve problem, call your hook in parent component and pass the states to Display components as props.

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-local-state-between-childrens-keipng). You need to use this way to update in one child components and use in another one.

If wont's props drilling, use Global state solution.

Comment: That's invalid, because `{}` means it's a body, not an object, but i instead tried `updateDates((prevState) => {return { ...prevState, to:e, from:s}});` and it does not make any difference

Comment: updated spelling typo

Comment: tried that way and it still does not make a difference my components using that hook are not updating when the hook is updating

Comment: Your update, again no change also why is `useCallback` supposed to be needed, my `setDateRange` never had a problem being called from the child components

Comment: If does not solved by using `useCallback`, can you please make monorepo version that present your current issue with codesandbox or stackblitz or share git link to check rendering problems more deeply.

Comment: i have added a codesandbox link to my post.

Comment: @Barkermn01, updated answer with solution and link

Comment: Thanks i will look in a bit, I'm still really flaming miffed so they made my code look light a right mess removing classes for absolutely no benefit to make this worse, code looks worse and a lot more cluttered, I still have to use parent to contain data for children, and worse reducers we're actually global...